# PHP: Is this syntax okay for calling a function with arguments?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there are any syntactic problems calling a function that only has one argument with multiple arguments.  For example:

```
function foobar( $biff ) {
// do stuff...
}
```

... and then call the function:

```
echo foobar( 'Hello', 'world', '!!!' )
```

I believe that `$biff === 'Hello'`, right?

And then I will use `array_slice( func_get_args(), 1 );` to play with the args `'world'` and `'!!!'`.

Is this right or is this not recommended?

P.S. I am working inside a function wrapper, which holds a lot of other functions containing various numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea should work, and it's perfectly valid : it's called [Variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) ; and it's not either "*right*" or "*wrong*".

If you need it, well, use it ;-)

One small problem, though, with the way you are using [`func_get_arg`](http://php.net/func_get_arg) : you cannot use it as a function parameter -- see the note at the bottom of the manual page.

The problem I see with this kind of idea is that you won't get hinting in your IDE -- which is not so nice when writing code :-(

So I would use this only when really necessary *(ie, when you really don't know how many parameters you need)*, even if it works fine.

Another option, if you know the mamimum number of possible arguments, would be to use [default / optionnal parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to define all expected arguments, and have optional arguments have a default value:

```
function foo($a, $b = '', $c = 1) { ... }
```

This way it's much more obvious what parameters can be given to a function.

Comment: That's not possible, unfortunately.  I'm working inside a function wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

your `array_slice` approach will only work in newer php versions (since 5.3)

otherwise your code is fine, but why don't you just put all three params in the function prototype?

Comment: I have it working on 5.2 right now. Mainly concerned if it's okay to call extra arguments with a function that only asks for one.

Comment: at least the php.net page says it only works since 5.3. calling with extra arguments doesn’t hurt, but as others said: you won’t have code completion in your ide and such

Answer (score 0):

[PHP: `func_get_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

> **Note:** Because this function depends on the current scope to determine parameter details, it cannot be used as a function parameter. If this value must be passed, the results should be assigned to a variable, and that variable should be passed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that'll work. PHP has a page which describes how this works, lists all of the variadic args related functions, and has some examples: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but as @Pascal Martin says, assign the arguments returned by func_get_arg to a variable before manipulating it. To get some code assist in your IDE, you can simply use PhpDoc notation:

```
/**
 * This function takes $biff and does yadayadayada. Additionally, more arguments 
 * can be passed in and will be used to ...
 * @param string $biff This argument will ...
 * @param string [$foo] Optional. Any number of arguments can be passed in and ..
 * @return string The return value of this function is $biff and any other 
 * parameters ...
 */
function foobar( $biff ) {
// do stuff...
}
```

This notation will give you code assist in Eclipse PDT, Zend Studio and probably a good few others.